# D2D1CreateFactory fails if D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION is set

Tags: c++, visual-c++, direct2d

The following code runs fine:

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS options;
    ZeroMemory( &options, sizeof( D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS ) );

#ifdef _DEBUG
//      options.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION;
#endif

    hr = D2D1CreateFactory(
        D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
        __uuidof( ID2D1Factory2 ),
        &options,
        &m_sp2DFactory
    );

    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;
```

However, if I remove the `//`, thus enabling the `D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION` I get:

```
hr: E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported.
```

My System is the latest Windows 10 TechPreview. I am using Visual Studio 2013. As far as I understand it, all DirectX Debugging libraries come with Visual Studio 2013. Is the `D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION` flag no longer supported? I couldn't find any info on that.

Comment: I think you doing something wrong. Check this example carefully: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee794277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What do you mean? My example is almost identical to the one presented by the website you posted, only that I take a method that uses slightly different parameter and since I am using VS 2013 there is no need to install the debug-layer separately. Or did I miss something?

Comment: I can see difference. In the example they passing parameters: `D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, options, &m_pD2DFactory);` while yours are different. Plz verify.

Comment: I am using this method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368034(v=vs.85).aspx which is also directly linked in your example webpage, and which funny enough is not the one used in the example. However, this shouldn't make any difference.